# How can I use Zeus for rake assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to get faster startup times for building my assets and would like to use Zeus. How can I use Zeus for `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`?

Answer (score 1):

```
zeus start
zeus rake assets:precompile
```

This [page](https://github.com/burke/zeus) has more details on how to get it working.

Comment: ````zeus rake```` is a valid command if you have installed zeus using ````gem install zeus```` and have a zeus.json in your directory like the example one here: https://github.com/burke/zeus/blob/master/examples/zeus.json

Comment: The ````zeus rake```` command is described in the zeus docs, [here](https://github.com/burke/zeus)

Comment: Hmm, I got an error: `No such file or directory -- zeus command: rake`. Seems I'm reading it wrong, it does say 'rake aborted' on the line below. My bad. Still, it doesn't seem to work in my environment, and it isn't giving me a useful error message. (If you edit your answer, I'll undo te -1.)

Comment: Strange.  Are you using RVM, RBENV, or something else? It might be something related to your ruby install.  Maybe putting --trace onto the end of your command gleans some helpful info.

Comment: I am actually using RVM, but my environment is just fine, and all other rake tasks are working like they should when invoked from within zeus. Precompiling assets outside zeus works well too. I have no idea what the issue might be. Anyway, undid the -1. :)

Comment: `zeus rake` works for me, but `zeus rake assets:precompile` fails with `No such file or directory -- zeus command: rake (LoadError)`